# How to set the window state to maximized of an external app

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, window

I am trying to set the windows style/state of a process/app (.exe) that i start using

```
ProcessStartInfo startinfo = someStartInfo //This contains the path of the exe file.
Process process = new Process();

process.Start()
```

to maximised but it does not work for all the apps.

I have tried setting `process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized`, i have also tried using the Main Window Handle of the process and setting it to maximized using ShowWindow win api but that also does not seem to work for all cases:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Exited += (sender, e) =>
{
    RebootMachine();
};

process.Start();

if (process != null)
{
    // Maximize the window using ShowWindow
    ShowWindowAsync(process.MainWindowHandle, SC_MAXIMIZE);
}

process.WaitForExit();
```

I have also tried using SendMessage the same way using the mainHandle something like this:

```
int WM_SIZE = 0x0005;
int SIZE_MAXIMIZED = 2;
SendMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, WM_SIZE, SIZE_MAXIMIZED, 0);
```

Is there a general solution that would work for all kind of apps, the current app i am trying this with is the calc.exe app.

I am also getting errors on some properties of the process variable when i debug it, it would be helpful if someone could provide some insight on that

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to use the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message with `SC_MAXIMIZE` wparam value.
Well-behaved programs will be correctly maximized, a few that cheat maximize state by manually repositioning window will not respond as expected.

POC in C. Will maximize the window given its handle in hex format.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if ( argc == 2 )
    {
        unsigned long int handle = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 16);
        if ( handle )
        {
            PostMessage((HWND)handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a general solution that would work for all kind of apps

In a word, no. As you already discovered, different apps can behave in different ways.

`WindowStyle` is just a request, not a guarantee. It can be ignored.

`MainWindowHandle` is determined hueristically, so it is not always accurate. Sometimes it picks the wrong window.

So, trying to control other people's apps may work most of the time, but unfortunately there is no 1 single approach that will work 100% of the time for 100% of all apps.

Comment: But how does windows achieve this when we press windows key + up arrow key? that does work for almost all applications i think, correct me if i am wrong. Thankyou.

Comment: @AnanduRamachandran that hotkey belongs to the OS itself, and the OS can do/force whatever it wants. Besides, you just said it works for *almost* all apps. The techniques you mentioned will work for well-behaved apps that follow common rules. But some apps just want to do their own things. Or they use UI designs that simply don't follow common practices.